# Angular js very simple example

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I'm learning AngularJS with WebStorm JetBrains, I have this very sample app, but it's not showing the array in the page when I press Debug button (it's open a webpage in Chrome like that:

> `http://localhost:63342/example/index.html`

I'm using the Plugin Connector for Chrome and I don't have errors in the Chrome console.

Where is my error? [Link to Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/5Ag53/)

**HTML (index.html)**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head lang="en">
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title></title>

    </head>

<body ng-app="webStorm" ng-controller="webStormController as ws">
<div ng-repeat="person in ws" ng-click="ws.showPerson(person)">
    {{person.firstName}}
</div>
<script type="text/javascript" src="bower_components/angular/angular.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="app.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

**JS (app.js)**

```
    var webStorm = angular.module("webStorm", []);
    webStorm.controller("webStormController", function(){
    var ws = this;
    ws.people = [{firstName: "John", lastName: "Smith"}];
    console.log(ws.people);
    ws.showPerson = function (person) {
        console.log(person);
    }
})
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<div ng-repeat="person in ws.people" ng-click="ws.showPerson(person)">
    {{person.firstName}}
</div>
```

change `person in ws` by `person in ws.people`

Comment: in starting  some time its happen no worries my friend cheers :)

Answer (score 1):

I think you meant: `ng-repeat="person in ws.people"`, that's the array you want to iterate :)